# How can i use the values of the dictionary to get an output table?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dictionary = {'Alex': [1,2,3], 'Tim': [4,5,6], ' Sally': [7,8,9]}
```

What I want is to draw a table having the names in the first line and the grades under each name, and I want it to be dynamic. Basically I won't have to interfere in anyway with the content in the dictionary (as in precise an exact name) just read every key in it.

I tried the following:

```
for x in range(size):
        table.append(dictionary[x])
        table.append(int(100 - 100 * dictionary[x] / B),)

for x in range (size*2+2):
    values.append(np.array(np.array(table[1:])[:, x+1],dtype=np.float32))
```

Note that 100 exists because in the actual code the numbers are basically being used to get a percentage divided by `B`, and in the `size*2+2` because I'm adding other characters but that won't matter in this question I'm asking.

(Running a python2.7)

Comment: why not use `pandas` ? something like https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html ?

Answer (score 0):

So this sounds like a homework question... I am going to give you some help but you will need to put in some work as well.
Here is the way to make a table where the first row prints the name of each person and under the name will be a grade for that student. (Python 3.6)

```
dictionary = {'Alex': [1,2,3], 'Tim': [4,5,6], 'Sally': [7,8,9]}
print("%s" % dictionary)

# print the names of the students
for key in dictionary:
    print("%s" % ('{0:%ds}' % (len(key) + 2)).format(key), end="")
print()

# print the grades under each student
i = 0
keys = list(dictionary.keys())

while i < len(keys):    
    j = 0
    while j < len(keys):
        values = list(dictionary.values())
        print("%s  " % ('{0:%dd}' % (len(keys[j]))).format(values[j][i]), end="")
        j = j + 1
    print()
    i = i + 1
```

Output:

```
{'Alex': [1, 2, 3], 'Tim': [4, 5, 6], 'Sally': [7, 8, 9]}
Alex  Tim  Sally  
   1    4      7  
   2    5      8  
   3    6      9
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As @Dadep said in the comment, you can load your dictionary into the pandas DataFrame this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dictionary = {'Alex': [1,2,3], 'Tim': [4,5,6], 'Sally': [7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
```

DataFrame is a table and you can perform operations over it's columns. The one we created looks like this if you print it:

```
   Alex  Sally  Tim
0     1      7    4
1     2      8    5
2     3      9    6
```

I am not sure, what operation you want to perform, but I will give you an example how you can add a column or edit one:

```
B = 10
df["Alex"] = (100 - 100 * df["Alex"] / B).apply(np.int64)   # Edit Alex column
df["Sally2"] = (100 - 100 * df["Sally"] / B).apply(np.int64)   # Make new Sally2 column
```

Then the table looks like this:

```
   Alex  Sally  Tim     Sally2
0    90      7    4         30
1    80      8    5         20
2    70      9    6         10
```

Note that if you will use pandas, all columns need to have same length.